# how to give the video's length to the progress's bar maximum value

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to convert the **Natural Duration** of the **Video file** into seconds because i want to set the maximum value of the progress bar. But i have an error like this **SPECIFIED CAST IS NOT VALID**.

```
          <ProgressBar Name="pb"  Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                       Value="{Binding ElementName=Video, Path=Position,
                       Converter={StaticResource progressbarconvert}}" 
                       Maximum="{Binding ElementName=Video,Path=NaturalDuration,
                       Converter={StaticResource progressbarconvert}}"></ProgressBar>
```

This my binding code for progress bar.

```
        TimeSpan t = (TimeSpan)value;
        int seconds = t.Seconds;
        seconds += t.Minutes * 60;
        seconds += t.Hours * 360;
        return seconds;
```

This is my converter code error. And i have an error in **TimeSpan t=(TimeSpan)value**. What is the Reason for this error. Is there any alternate solution to give the video's length to the progress bar's maximum value???

Comment: Why not just do `return (int)t.TotalSeconds;`? Also when you debug, what is the type of `value` in the debugger if you do `value.GetType()`?

Comment: Actually the value type is Automatic because i am using Natural Duration so returns automatic value. It shows the time after the video is playing. Scott could you help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Ateik has the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

First the NaturalDuration is of type Duration, so the casting would be different than Position
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.naturalduration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Second, when you cast to duration, you need to check the value HasTimeSpan, because if the video is not loaded and played you wont have this value yet